# Question closed due to non-question format -- rewritten

Tags: support, reopen-request, review

I recently had a question closed due to it being labeled as not a real quesiton, so I just rewrote the question and wanted to ask if it could be opened again and also, if the negative score could be zeroed out.

The link is at: https://superuser.com/questions/324853/imaging-software-reliability-and-alternatives-to-the-big-names

Comment: There are a ton of questions that ask the exact same thing as yours.  If it was to be reopened, I would just flag it as a duplicate... But that would take more work on my part this time.  Maybe ***you* should do a search** before posting.  Hint: clonezilla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question still doesn't have an actual problem there. It is trying to hedge your bets on picking out software that will not create a possibly corrupted backup file.

The following searches should help you out:

- [+clone windows](https://superuser.com/search?q=%2Bclone+%5Bwindows%5D)
- [+corrupted +backup](https://superuser.com/search?q=%2Bcorrupted+%2Bbackup)

Have a clear problem and ask it directly - don't tack on extra questions as they come to you. Pause and ask in a clear and concise way.

Comment: My apologies. Thanks for pointing that out.